# Identifying a film that involved a giant man-bat with lower human limbs

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember a short screening at movie world around 2003-2006 that sparked my memory of a giant man-bat with lower human limbs.I don't believe the excerpt was linked to any horror genre as I was fairly young when my parents took me.

I only recall a particular scene where the creature has its wings outstretched in a cave and a swarm of normal bats circling around it. Prior to my memory of that scene there were two men (one young, one elderly) who were about to enter its territory whose intents were harmless; they were possibly seeking advice/wisdom from the creature.

Comment: Not an answer because I didn't find about the cave part nor the bats circling around, but the man-bat with lower human limbs makes me think of [Francis Ford Coppola's Dracula](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzyeGBdQmCM) (1992), all along with the young and old men (Johnathan Harker and Abraham Van Helsing). It could be any incarnation of Dracula, from Van Helsing or Dracula Untold, altough I did not see those ones. Could as well be the nightmarish version of Batman in Batman Begins.

Answer (score 3):

Could this possibly be the Gaoul scene from [Titan A.E.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120913/)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It wasn't a cartoon. I definitely remember it as a non-animated film. The bat had a life-like physique and looked like an animatronic prop