# Space opera anime show, protagonist has a spaceship and a medal in the back of his hand

Tags: story-identification, tv, anime

I saw it as a kid when I was growing up in the Middle East. It must have been from the late 80s or early 90s.

The premise was a protagonist who has a medallion or medal which fits on the back of his hand, who also had a spaceship. There was also an episode in which they interact with kangaroo-looking creatures. I think it's very obscure.

Comment: [Lensman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DDzNCpBgEVM)?

Comment: Are you thinking of the gaoul scene from Titan A.E.? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90558/identifying-a-film-that-involved-a-giant-man-bat-with-lower-human-limbs

Comment: No unfortunately. It was definitely a japanese anime show. Very distinctive, very dark. I was only 5 or 6 but was immediately enthralled.

Answer (score 7):

[Lensman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lensman_(1984_film)) (ＳＦ新世紀 レンズマン SF Shinseiki Lensman, lit. "Science Fiction New Century Lensman") 1984

Lensmen are sort of super-policemen/secret-agents. One has vital information that has to be brought to the Galactic Patrol. The evil Boskone empire almost kills him, but he crash lands on a sleepy backwater farming planet. There he gives the local farm boy Kimball Kinnision the Lens onto the back of his hand, and tells him to get it to the Galactic Patrol. Then the Lensman dies.

[image: Kimball Kinnision]

Kimball doesn't know what to do, but is soon befriended by another Lensman, who is part dragon but does admittedly look a bit like a kangaroo. His name is Worsel.

[image: Worsel]

He teaches Kimball how to use the Lens, and runs interference against Boskone to allow Kim to complete the mission.